# Как открыть web-приложение mysql, php. Mac

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование, mac, веб-служба

Есть веб приложение на php+mysql для работы с бд. Включил через MAMP, Apache. Включил mysql. Открыл в phpmyadmin бд. Перенес в папку htdocs, папку с всеми доками веб приложения. Переходя на ссылку localhost/gum (gum название проекта и бд). Выдает ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если просто `localhost` ?

Comment: Пишет, Welcome to XAMPP for OS X 7.3.28

Comment: Что и требовалось доказать. Всё работает прекрасно. Непонятно как и куда вы перенесли файлы веб приложения, но их нет в том каталоги, в котором нужно. И непонятно какое отношение gum в БД имеет к структуре каталогов веб сервера

Comment: А хост вы прописали?

Comment: Где можно посмотреть и как прописать хост?

Comment: Перенес файлы в папку htdocs приложение MAMP

Comment: @Wessber если не ошибаюсь, в xampp папка `XAMPP\apache\conf\extra` файл `httpd-vhosts.conf` - в него надо хост вписать, там есть пример как это делается

Comment: можно глупый вопрос, а какой хост?) (я нашел папку, но не понял что вписывать) :(